# In an array, are the elements stored Primitives or Objects?

Tags: java

```
int[] array = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
}
```

in this example, is the value 0 stored inside the array as a primitive or as an object?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the value is stored as a primitive. If you changed the type to a primitive's *wrapper* `Integer`, the value would go in as an "auto-boxed" `Object` then. For example, this code would autobox your values:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[10];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, there are both arrays of primitives, and arrays of objects.

`int[]` is an array of primitives, so `0` is stored as a primitive.

The corresponding array of objects would be of type `Integer[]`. Storing `0` in such an array would result in it being "auto-boxed" into an `Integer` object.

It is worth pointing out that Java containers (and any other generic classes) can only work with objects. For example, it is impossible to construct a `List` of `int`, only a `List` of `Integer`. As I've explained above, this restriction does not apply to arrays.